# Windows 2 NICs same subnet and different networks

Tags: networking, windows-8, routing

I'm a bit puzzled about an issue I had today (btw i'm not a network expert, even less a Windows one)

Suppose I have 2 NICs,

- Wi-fi with address `192.168.1.71/255.255.255.0`
- Ethernet with `192.168.1.20/255.255.255.0`

The Ethernet is **directly connected** with a device with address `192.168.1.55/255.255.255.0`.

Supose there is a web server on that device.

I don't know the routes established on the system and i cannot check them, but the Wifi was first and the Ethernet was modified explicitly to have that address (the system is Windows 8)

I suppose at that time the route print command should show this (among other entries)

```
192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.1.71 yy

192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.1.20 xx
```

The question is: if I try now to connect to 192.168.1.55:80 (and supposing there is no machine on the wifi with that ip), will it be possible to establish the connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are two networks with the same parameters (as in your example), the OS chooses the network interface with the lowest metric to send traffic out. You can view the interface metric by `netstat -rnv`.

You can modify the metric values by going to the network card's properties, select IPv4, click Properties, click Advanced and disable Automatic metric and put in a manual value.

Comment: So there's no possibility of reaching 192.168.1.55 supposing that yy is lesser than xx ? I mean, if the connection fails because there is no such 192.168.1.55 on the network reachable from 192.168.1.71 (the Wifi) it does not falls back to the Ethernet(20) interface ?